# youtube api v3 insert comments

Tags: javascript, api, youtube, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api

i am trying to use the youtube api v3 to insert comments by using javascript as explained in:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps .

i have registered the project, activated the youtube api option in the developer console and was able to get proper oath token. but when trying to post a comment i keep getting this message:

"code 403. Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup"

in the oath javascript guide it was said that: 
"If the API returns an HTTP 403 response code, then your application may not be registered. Many APIs set a query-volume limit of 0 for unregistered applications and return a 403 response code when the query-volume limit is exceeded."

i have looked everywhere but i don't know where to set up the query volume...any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

This may actually be an issue of authentication. If you don't authenticate your account and attempt to insert comments, you'll be blocked from doing so. I would double check to see if you correctly pass the access token along in your authentication flow

Also make sure comments are enabled (aka the video isn't deleted/privated/etc)